# Transcribing address from New York 1870 marriage certificate

Tags: marriage-records, new-york-city, transcriptions, 1870s

I am having trouble transcribing an address from a New York marriage certificate from 1870. Hopefully someone with knowledge of the area and time might be able to see it as I am unfamiliar with the area. There is a fair amount of handwriting to compare to.

The 2. Place of residence - is the trouble "East something something"

I'm guessing it's a New York address, but it could be further afield as I have no other information for him.

On the marriage application there's another address, but I think it's the registrars office: "44 W 32nd St. New York"

My transcription is

RETURN OF A MARRIAGE.

1. Full Name of HUSBAND,    John MacArthur
2. Place of Residence,      East ????? ???
3. Age next Birthday,       43
4. Occupation,              Book Keeper
5. Place of Birth,          Scotland
6. Father's Name,.          Gilbert MacArthur
7. Mother's Maiden Name,    Isabella MacArthur
8. No. of Husband's Marriage,   Second
9. Full Name of WIFE.      Mary Ellen Sunley
   Maiden Name, if a Widow,
10. Place of Residence,     New York City
11. Age next birthday,      34
12. 
13. Place of Birth.     New York City
14. Father's Name,      Richard Sunley
15. Mother's Maiden Name    Sarah Roebuck
16. No. of Wife's Marriage, One

[image]

Comment: BTW, I think that "Z" that you've got in the "Maiden name, if a Widow" is the top of the Y from New York.

Comment: Thanks yes, I think I initially grabbed the transcript from Mac Preview which can do the printed text quite well. I didn't spot that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like [East Templeton, Mass.](https://www.templetonma.gov/home/slideshows/east-templeton) to me.

The "Ma" from "Mass" matches the "Ma" from "MacArthur."
The "T" looks like a "T," and the end looks like "letin" or "leton."
The "emp" could have been "ens" or "emp," and a search revealed the existence of an "East Templeton, Mass."

Comment: Great. He had a brother in Ipswich Mass. so this is quite likely. I did consider Temple something but the o seemed wrong compared to his other o. Perhaps he thought it was Templetin!